# Build Frank with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, build, cocoapods, ui-testing, frank

I'm trying build Frank with my xcode app that use Cocoapods.

Setup (`frank setup`) is ok.

After setup i ran `frank build`. I get error. After some research i ran:

```
frank build --workspace my_app.xcworkspace/ --scheme my_app
```

and result was:

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
    Check dependencies
    Check dependencies
    Check dependencies
```

After another research i have tried to specify architecture. So i tried to build app using:

```
frank build --workspace my_app.xcworkspace/ --scheme my_app  --arch armv7s
```

I have tried architecture `armv7`, `armv7s` and `arm64`. Result is always something like this (sometime is error for Alamofire and other pods):

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwiftSources normal armv7s com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwift normal armv7s /path/Pods/Kingfisher/Kingfisher/ImageCache.swift
    CompileSwift normal armv7s /path/Pods/Kingfisher/Kingfisher/ImageDownloader.swift
    CompileSwift normal armv7s /path/Pods/Kingfisher/Kingfisher/ImageTransition.swift
    CompileSwift normal armv7s /path/Pods/Kingfisher/Kingfisher/KingfisherManager.swift
(5 failures)
```

After another research i have tried add include of pods to `frankify.xcconfig`

```
#include "path/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig"
```

which solves nothing.

Does anybody have an idea what am i doing wrong? I am stuck.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have submitted issue on github but i still haven't get any feedback.

Comment: Just like you say. Calabash or UI Testing in Xcode for iOS only in my case.