# How can I get Frank to play nicely with Cocoapods and interface-builder (Rubymotion)

Tags: ios, cocoapods, rubymotion, frank

I've been trying all day to get Frank to work well in my RubyMotion app. This is becoming quite stressful, any help would be appreciated.

What I've done so far:

- Built an app. The app includes Cocoapods and the `ib` gem.
- Installed the frank gem `gem install frank-cucumber`
- ran `frank setup` (All seems to work fine so far...)
- ran `frank build` (This is where :poop: hits the fan)

see below:

```
remove  Frank/frankified_build
   run  xcodebuild -xcconfig Frank/frank.xcconfig clean build  -arch i386 -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES DSTROOT="/Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/Frank/frankified_build" FRANK_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS="\"/Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/Frank\""  from "."
Build settings from command line:
ARCHS = i386
DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION = YES
DSTROOT = /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/Frank/frankified_build
FRANK_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = "/Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/Frank"
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO
SDKROOT = iphonesimulator9.3

Build settings from configuration file 'Frank/frank.xcconfig':
FRANK_CORE_LDFLAGS = -all_load -ObjC -framework CFNetwork -framework Security -lShelley -lCocoaAsyncSocket -lCocoaLumberjack -lCocoaHTTPServer -lFrank
FRANK_CORE_MAC_LDFLAGS = -all_load -ObjC -framework CFNetwork -framework Security -lShelleyMac -lCocoaAsyncSocketMac -lCocoaLumberjackMac -lCocoaHTTPServerMac -lFrankMac
FRANK_GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_NOT_USED_IN_PRECOMPS = $(FRANK_CORE_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_NOT_USED_IN_PRECOMPS)
FRANK_LDFLAGS = $(FRANK_LDFLAGS_$(PLATFORM_NAME))
FRANK_LDFLAGS_iphoneos = $(FRANK_CORE_LDFLAGS)
FRANK_LDFLAGS_iphonesimulator = $(FRANK_LDFLAGS_iphoneos)
FRANK_LDFLAGS_macosx = $(FRANK_CORE_MAC_LDFLAGS)
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_NOT_USED_IN_PRECOMPS = FRANKIFIED
INSTALL_PATH = /./

=== CLEAN TARGET ib OF PROJECT ib WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Clean.Remove clean build/UninstalledProducts/iphonesimulator/libib.a
builtin-rm -rf /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/UninstalledProducts/iphonesimulator/libib.a

Clean.Remove clean build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build
builtin-rm -rf /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build

Clean.Remove clean build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libib.a
builtin-rm -rf /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libib.a

** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

=== BUILD TARGET ib OF PROJECT ib WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Write auxiliary files
write-file /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/ib-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/Objects-normal/i386
write-file /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/Objects-normal/i386/ib.LinkFileList
write-file /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/ib-project-headers.hmap
write-file /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/ib-all-target-headers.hmap
write-file /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/ib-own-target-headers.hmap
write-file /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/ib.hmap
write-file /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/ib-generated-files.hmap

SymLink build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libib.a build/UninstalledProducts/iphonesimulator/libib.a
cd /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/Gavin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/Users/Gavin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin:/Users/Gavin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/Users/Gavin/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/heroku/bin"
/bin/ln -sfh /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/UninstalledProducts/iphonesimulator/libib.a /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libib.a

CompileC build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/Objects-normal/i386/Stubs.o ib.xcodeproj/Stubs.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS
export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/Gavin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/Users/Gavin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin:/Users/Gavin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/Users/Gavin/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/heroku/bin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=202 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fmodules-ignore-macro=FRANKIFIED -fbuild-session-file=/var/folders/qh/gr7t4tsj2_x_4lp5mkyvcw0r0000gn/C/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mios-simulator-version-min=9.3 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -iquote /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/ib-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/ib-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/ib-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/ib-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -DFRANKIFIED -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/Objects-normal/i386/Stubs.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/Objects-normal/i386/Stubs.dia -c /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/ib.xcodeproj/Stubs.m -o /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/Objects-normal/i386/Stubs.o
In file included from /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/ib.xcodeproj/Stubs.m:4:
/Users/Gavin/Clients/TheApp/iOS/ib.xcodeproj/Stubs.h:10:9: fatal error: 'CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h' file not found
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h>
  ^
1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
CompileC build/ib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ib.build/Objects-normal/i386/Stubs.o ib.xcodeproj/Stubs.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

As you can see, it's freaking out because it can't find `CoreAudio`, which I believe is included by one of the pods I've installed (I haven't included it).

It seems to be because Frank is treating the xcodeproject created by IB as the main app: `In file included from /Users/Gavin/Clients/TheRevelry/iOS/ib.xcodeproj/Stubs.m:4:`

I've tried the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605135/build-frank-with-cocoapods) but they don't work (There aren't any other workspaces in my app).

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this, however it seems like [frank-cucumber](https://github.com/moredip/Frank) is a Ruby gem and not a Rubymotion gem, which is not the same.

Maybe what you are looking for is this Rubymotion gem [motion-frank](https://github.com/cyrusinnovation/motion-frank)?

Comment: You're right, I confused the names of the gems in my question. So the problem persists, but it's with `motion-frank`

Comment: Ok, sorry, then I can't be of more help.